# How to change "name" and "value" when writing output of dict in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

When running this "script":

```
$datadict = @{'One' = 1; 'Two' = 2; };

foreach($data in $datadict) {
    Write-Output $datadict;
}
```

How do I change the "Name" and the "Value" string output in Powershell:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
One                            1
Two                            2
```

Comment: `$datadict|ft @{l='NotName';e='Name'},@{l='NotValue';e='Value'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through the keys and use a psobject like so:

```
$datadict.keys | % {
    New-object psobject -Property @{
        'new name 1' = $_
        'new name 2' = $datadict[$_]    
    }
}
```

Output would be this:

```
new name 1 new name 2
---------- ----------
One                 1
Two                 2
```